# android studio - out of memory

Tags: android, android-studio

recently I get this dialog that android studio says "out of memroy"

[image]

I've 6Gb ram , how can I increase this value to allocate more memory to my android studio ?

Answer (score 0):

Increase Xmx size then clean Android Studio cache then restart.

Comment: You can set Xmx size randomly.

Answer (score 0):

You should click `Help > Edit Custom VM Options...` menu of Android Studio and write option what you want like the following.

```
# custom Android Studio VM options, see https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html
-Xmx4096m
```